# python SAML in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, saml

Is there a library I can use to do a SAML authentication in App Engine using python?

I've looked at [pysaml2](https://github.com/rohe/pysaml2) which does say it's pure python implementation. However, it's using subprocess.Popen which cannot be used within App Engine and will fail at that point.

Answer (score 2):

You can use python-saml on GAE if you use the flex environment with a custom runtime built off of the [standard python27](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-runtime) runtime [provided by google](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/customizing-the-python-runtime).  I just got onelogin's [python-saml flask-demo](https://github.com/onelogin/python-saml#demo-flask-1) successfully working with this approach using the following settings:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/python
LABEL python_version=python
RUN virtualenv /env -p python

# Install system packages for onelogin dependencies not already included in runtime
RUN apt-get update && apt-get --yes --quiet install python2.7-dev libxmlsec1-dev

# Set virtualenv environment variables. This is equivalent to running
# source /env/bin/activate
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH
ADD requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /app/
CMD python index.py
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
entrypoint: python index.py

api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
```

requirements.txt

```
flask==0.10.1
python-saml
```

then simply do `gcloud app deploy app.yaml --version v1`

Comment: note: flexible environment and custom runtimes are in beta still

Comment: is that possible to run flexible env (in a seperate service) and standard env in single app? Because I have to implement python-saml in flexible env and all other codes should use standard env

Answer (score 0):

Try [python-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/python-saml) or [python3-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml)

Comment: It seems as though `python-saml` requires the package `dm.xmlsec.binding` which is a Cython binding to `xmlsec`, so my guess would be that this is where it will fail.
However, I no longer have access to the project that required this, so I was unable to test this.