# Google App Engine Standard Environment (Python + SAML)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, saml-2.0, google-app-engine-python

Are there any libraries that are supported in App Engine Standard Python architecture to provide SAML 2.0 support?

This post suggests using App Engine Flex and the python-saml library using a Docker image: [python SAML in GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31599304/python-saml-in-gae)

I've tried this method, but you lose out on some of the Standard-only features like the X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid header, which is stripped when making calls from a Flex environment, and using the native Datastore is more of a pain.

If there are no Python-native libraries currently supported in AES-Python, do one of the other standard-supported languages (Java, PHP, Go) have a native solution for SAML 2 SSO integrations that I could spin up as a separate service?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the [`python-saml` library](https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/python) doesn't have C-based source code, you can [install it as a third-party library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library) following the directions in the docs.

Comment: Unfortunately it depends on libxml2 and a couple other packages that are C-based, which is why the Flex environment + Docker img was necessary.

Comment: In the bundled third-party libraries `lxml` says it provides a "pythonic binding for `lxml2`". That dependency might be taken care of, not sure about the others. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27

Comment: Wow, I must have missed this built-in library or it was added more recently. I'll test deploying to standard with the `lxml` library and see if it plays nicely with python-saml

Comment: @yoonjesung did the built-in library work with python-saml in standard appengine environment?